# Unwanted Boldness in input - HTML

Tags: html, css

I have to buttons "YES" and "NO" as shown in below images

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**For YES**

**HTML**

```
<div class="margin-1half-em padding-zero text-center" >
        <input type="button" class="login-btn cursor-pointer padding-left-1em padding-right-1em" value="YES">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.login-btn {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 0.15em 0.75em;
  color: #012258;
  background: #15DB00;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #666;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #666;
  font-family: FTR55;
}
```

**For NO**

**HTML**

```
<div class="margin-1half-em padding-zero text-center" >
    <input type="button" class="login-btn padding-left-1em padding-right-1em" style="background-color: red; color: white;" value="NO">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.login-btn {
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      padding: 0.15em 0.75em;
      color: #012258; // Overridden for no
      background: #15DB00; // Overridden for no
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.2vw;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #666;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #666;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #666;
      font-family: FTR55;
    }
```

**Problem:** Text **NO** is more bold then text **YES**. I have no idea why this happens ?

**P.S:** Padding and margin classes are just for padding and margins nothing else.

Comment: I don't see any difference between them.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal "NO" is much bolder then "YES" .

Comment: Maybe it is just an optical illusion?

Comment: I added another image too for more clarification.

Comment: Both image having same font-size display. To prove yourself type text yes in place of no.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I added another one, please see them in detail. Thanks

Comment: I just compared the characters in photoshop and they have the same weight. As Bhohendra said, just try to type yes instead of no and compare them.

Comment: There's no difference at all. The difference what you see is because of color one is blue and another is white and as per the color variation the eye is catching different. Blue color in green background almost disappears from the eye..

Comment: I don't get it. They are the same, aren't they?

Comment: yep..think it might be drugs?

Comment: I can see the white colored text is bolder. but seeing deeply you may find they are same as blue color is fading..

Comment: Both have the same boldness.

Comment: @Junaid That's not html or css problem however. It's just a color illusion

Comment: @BhojendraNepal any work around for this ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gaz5ohjrlcx76yo/BoldVsBold.PNG?dl=0 But there is now way to change them.

Comment: AS @Christoph has put the image in dropbox, you may see the font-size display is exactly the same. But in smaller view white seems be bolder than blue as white color is caught in green background but not properly the blue color by the eyes.

Comment: Some displays (particularly CRTs) may show more difference between the two buttons than others, so, what kind of screen are you viewing this on?